# Horizontal Bar In Word Counting

Tags: c

So I have been trying to solve a problem about printing a histogram of the lenghts of words in its input and question indicates it is easy to draw it horizontally so thats what I tried but when I write `HELLO WORLD` I get  `1 = -----` which is correct and `2 = ----` which is 4 lines instead of 5 meaning False output.
To understand the problem I added putchar to my code and I realized that compiler  doesnt count the  'w' of the world can anyone explain why?

```
OUTPUT:
HELLO ORLD
1== -----
2==----
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    int c, word = 1;
    int lenght[MAX];
    int state = IN;
    int leng = 0;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        lenght[i] = 0;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && word < MAX)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        {
            state = OUT;
        }
        else if (state == IN)
        {
            leng++;
            putchar(c);
        }
        else if (state == OUT)
        {
            putchar(' ');
            lenght[word] = leng;
            word++;
            leng = 0;
            state = IN;
        }
    }
    lenght[word] = leng;
    for (i = 1; i <= word; ++i)
    {
        printf("%3d: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < lenght[i]; j++)
            putchar('-');
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: After you read the first word HELLO, comes an empty char `' '`. In this case it will be on a OUT state, given that's the first if. Then for the next character will be the `W`, but the state will be OUT yet, so it will be evaluated on the last condition `else if (state == OUT) `. That's why is not taking W as a character of a word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ignoring the first character of every but the first word.

Assuming input `HELLO WORLD`:

- First word is counted properly.
- At the space character, the first `if`-branch is taken, `state` gets set to `OUT`. The space character is not processed.
- At `W`, the last `if`-branch is taken, outputting a space. The current character is not processed and `leng` gets set to `0` even though we already saw the first character.
- consequently `W` is not output and the length of the rest of the word sums up to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for not having the patience to understand the logic of your program and find the bug. However here is an alternative approach that you may prefer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    char word[SIZE];  
    int lengths[MAX], i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; scanf(" %s", word) == 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d = ", i);

        for (j = 0; word[j] != '\0'; j++) {

            printf("-");
        }

        lengths[i] = j;
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question ı am trying to solve is WAP to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input.It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal my logic was to count the letters in each word and then get output of '-'   for each letter of that word when ı write hello it gives 5 '-' which is correct but when ı write hello world it gives 5 lines for the first word and 4 lines for the second one ı am trying to understand why it gives the correct output for the first word and false output for the others

Comment: If the question is *can anyone explain why*, presenting a different solution to the problem does not answer the question.

Comment: @Emeraldo I added an array that keeps track of the lengths of the words

Comment: @flyx I pointed it out at the beginning of the answer and providing a different solution that is more readable and thus easier to debug is actually a nice help

Comment: @Davide your code also helped me a lot it is more readible and logical but ı had some restrictions given by my teacher and ı had to write it like ı did in my code thats why ı was trying to figure out the bug anyway thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Emeraldo no thank you for appreciating my efforts